# web workers with set timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-worker

I have a problem with a really expansive function that do calculations about the state(react).
I call this function regularly every 100ms

The bad function:

```
 const reallyExpansiveFunc =()=>{
   calculations...
   }
```

I call her in setTimeout that way:

```
  useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(()=>{
  reallyExpansiveFunc()
},100)},[[reallyExpansiveFunc, data]])
```

the problem is that it takes to much time and it blocks the stack so my browser can't do anything

I thought about solving this with web workers so my react component will do only the rendering of the data and the calculations will be done by the browser.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      calcWorker.onmessage = ($event) => {
          if ($event && $event.data) {
              setData($event.data);
          }
      };
  }, [calcWorker]);

  function reallyExpansiveFunc() {
      calcWorker.postMessage({msg: 'reallyExpansiveFunc', data: data});
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setData(reallyExpansiveFunc())
      },100)
  }, [reallyExpansiveFunc, data])
```

and on another file the worker and the expansive function declaration:

```
self.onmessage = async ($event) => {
    if ($event && $event.data && $event.data.msg === 'changeData') {
        const calcResult = changeData($event.data.data);
        self.postMessage(calcResult );
    }
};
```

My question is, is the web worker is gonna help? I'm not sure because I already used setTimeout.

Comment: It really depends on what `reallyExpansiveFunc` does, if it's all CPU bound, and not IO bound, then a webworker should help yes..  A side note, a `setTimeout` will execute on the same thread, so it's not the same as a webworker..

Comment: is `reallyExpansiveFunc` asynchronous ?

Comment: thank you Keith that helped.
and no ```reallyExpansiveFunc ``` is not async